# Selecting Earliest date from String of dates in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm trying to grab the earliest and last date from mySQL database. Its a string of dates like the following:

```
2015-04-02, 2015-04-03, 2015-04-04, 2015-04-05
```

I want to be able to grab the earliest date: `2015-04-02` and last date: `2015-04-05.`

Hoping I could do this directly with a MYSQL query, any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: There is no such function in mysql to do it, you should never store comma separated values to avoid this kind of issue. Better do it in application level, you can use `PHP explode` function and get the min and max value from the array.

Comment: are they always in date order?

Comment: @pala_ Yes they will always be in order.

Comment: then ignore @AbhikChakraborty, there is a mysql function to do it, my answer is below.

Comment: @pala_ are you encouraging ignoring the basic normalization part ? If so then thats a bad suggestion by you. However for ordered data you can use `substring_index` I dont deny that but its time for you too have a look at the normalization.

Comment: no. i'm encouraging him to ignore the part where you said 'there is no such function to do it'.  the question wasn't "what is the best way to store a series of dates", it was "how do i get what i want from the data i have". I'll note that  you also did not suggest data normalization, you simply said 'you cant do it in mysql. do it in php'. you were wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dates are always in order, you can do this:

```
SELECT substring_index(date_string, ',', 1) first_date,
       substring_index(date_string, ',', -1) last_date;
```

Comment: Worked great! Thank you so much!